# Plugin to allow for recurrent subscription + exclusive content

Tags: plugins, subscription

Recently my step-mom lost her freelancing gig with a couple of newspapers. She ran a fairly prominent feature about two shows, and decided to take her writing elsewhere, setting up her own website to use.

She did some initial probing of her userbase and they all said they'd be willing to pay $5 or so a month to be able to read the stuff that my step-mom writes, but obviously we don't want for these posts to be viewable to anyone outside of the subscribers or herself.

Anyone here use anything? I've seen something to do with woocommerce pop up, and quite a few other places that charge a good bit to be used, but I have no experience with them so I'm hesitant to commit to one I have no feedback about.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: downvoter care to explain ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need a couple plugins to do this. I use Woocommerce for just about everything - there is a ton of plugins and a lot of support online.

Get Woocommerce for free through the wordpress repository. Set up your store through there. Then you will need Woocommerce subscription & Woocommerce Membership - it is the best to use for something like this.

Get a free membership over at gpldl.com - a great site where you can download these woocmmerce plugins for free once you are signed up. Once signed up - go to  https://gpldl.com/repository/premium-woocommerce-extensions/ and get "WooThemes Subscriptions WooCommerce Extension" and install it. Finally - you will want "WooCommerce - Memberships WooCommerce Extension" which can also be downloaded at gpldl.com.

Once you have these plugins - you should be able to follow the setup instructions and get your membership site up and running.

Comment: hmm, Interesting. I'll look into that on a non-live install to make sure that i can get it to do what she needs. Thanks Doug!